# Is there a simple way to pursue OT question as NAA with maximum prejudice in the flag-queue?

Tags: discussion

I started looking at the flag queue again the other day, and there seems to be a lot of this going on.  Is there a way to implement a custom flag for this so we can call it how it is without violating the don't flag NAA as custom thing since it's a vastly more specific thing?

Example:
Q: How do I resolve some issue with XYZ?
A: You do this.

another answer:
A: I have this same problem but on this other forked distro.  How do I get it working on Mint?
(or insert some other blob part to the asking a question as an answer that makes it off-topic)

So the not an answer flag fits, but it seems weird to me that there were so many of these cropping up recently.  It also seems like a more severe misuse of the system than "Thanks" or "Me too."

Comment: So you want to sort the flag queue so you see these on top so to speak? It's not really that different from a normal "me too" IMHO..

Comment: @Seth - Yes.  The heuristic for it would be tough to do, but a human being able to say - NAA and is off-topic.  More than just a Me too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Seth points out, there's a bit of confusion over whether you mean Questions or Answers but in both cases just *voting against it* is pretty prejudicial.

If you get a whole load of downvotes, you'll likely end up banned from answering for a while.

Comment: hold up let me find an example

Comment: Wait, we have quality Answers ban?

Comment: @Braiam There are automated bans for asking, answering, suggesting edits and reviewing.

Comment: Err.. "reviewing", really? I'm only aware of the audits that bans you automatic (for the others I know, but the [question quality ban](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7194/169736) but for answers was the one I was refering to)