# Don't we have a "minimum quality" filter?

Tags: support, asking-questions, low-quality-posts

Please don't mixup with [Quality blocks enabled for questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7194/quality-blocks-enabled-for-questions).

For some time now, I've seen the system accepting low quality stuff, without capitalized I's, a mess of punctuation signs, all-caps questions, and other indicators that the asker has poor language skills. Are these checks not enabled in Ask Ubuntu?

I'm asking about this [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/213575)

Comment: You should think of the poor newcomers - how else can one gain rep easily /get one's feet wet if not by improving such questions. ;-)

Comment: @guntbert answering questions >:)

Comment: My brief experience is that posts without capitalized "i"'s are often poor quality in other respects too. My vote is for punting such posts back to OP somehow and asking them to fix it as a compulsory ticket to being accepted on SE.

Comment: @DKBose That actually already happens, somewhat. This question is about tweaking the filter a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're enabled. Roughly 35 blocked in the past day.

They're not perfect; the quality score is generated from a number of different heuristics, with the end result being questions that do very well by some measures and very poorly by others getting through.

We *might* want to bump up the threshold at which a question is held back. A good indication of this are questions that end up in [the Low Quality /review queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/history), since it is driven by the same heuristics as the block. So if you're seeing a lot of stuff there that should've been blocked outright, post examples here.

Comment: Uhhh... that's somehow a low number.

Comment: Without anything to compare it to, I'm not sure how you're evaluating it.

Comment: Well, for example this http://askubuntu.com/q/436840/169736

Comment: Yeah, that would *never* be blocked given the current algorithm used for quality checks. It has multiple tags, a full sentence as a title, and multiple paragraphs in the body complete with punctuation and capitalization and so on. Compared to the sort of thing the automated quality checks were designed to block, it's practically Strunk & White.

Comment: Yeh, bad example, I need to find one... D:

Comment: Found it, http://askubuntu.com/revisions/df3f0dda-06e3-4fbb-bebc-ae55c89626aa/view-source

Comment: Ha! That would've been blocked on Stack Overflow, but a particular setting here allowed it through. I've adjusted this setting - thanks @Braiam.

Comment: It broke again :( http://askubuntu.com/posts/447189/revisions and there's something to prevent these? http://askubuntu.com/questions/447135/motorola-atrix-ubuntu

Comment: Not quite sure what happened there, @Braiam - that should have been blocked, and several variations on it by the same author *were* blocked - it appears he found a variation that wasn't, but whatever it was I'm missing it.

Comment: MM... http://askubuntu.com/q/491838/169736